# How much disk space needed for a single system restore point?

Tags: windows

I'm not very familiar with windows' system restore mechanism, but wondering how much disk space is necessary (I just want to create my own single restore point)?

I just don't need windows to create restore point automatically, so I can reduce preserved disk space.

**UPDATE**

OS: Windows XP SP3 Enu

Comment: Just tell Windows how much disk space to use.

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/210297/where-are-the-windows-7-system-restore-points-stored-and-how-to-preserve-them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[reading about restore points](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/system-restore-frequently-asked-questions) you can find the section "How much hard disk space does System Restore require?":

> To store restore points, you need at least 300 megabytes (MB) of free
>   space on each hard disk that has System Protection turned on. System
>   Restore might use up to 15 percent of the space on each disk. As the
>   amount of space fills up with restore points, System Restore will
>   delete older restore points to make room for new ones.
>
> System Restore will not run on hard disks smaller than 1 gigabyte
>   (GB).

Comment: Yeah , I just realized even the restore point I creataed manually are replaced..